# Blender Face and Body Capture using a iphone camera or mov file

Tags: animation

What is the best blender capture software or addon to do full body and face capture live or from a mov file.

Answer (score 0):

For now, you can use any software like [Radical](https://getrad.co) and you can use to import a BVH file using this [Unity Program](https://github.com/digital-standard/ThreeDPoseTracker) and yes, you can use video as a input.

There is OpenCV which can be a potential mocap solution for Blender but for now we can do this.